# How to simulate input click, press space and backspace wih jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, keypress, keycode

I'm trying to simulate click (focus), type space (" ") and delete the space typed evet with jQuery to trigger change on input fields. (Tried all trigger events but it doesn't work)

Tried this but no luck;

```
$('input[name="title"]').trigger(jQuery.Event('keypress', {keyCode: 87, which: 13}));
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just have both call a function and use it separately?

Comment: For a clean code, i have 20 more lines like this.

Comment: I don't mean why are you doing it with this method, I mean why are you doing it like this at all.

Comment: Oh because I override an input made in vue.js, I need to mimic the type so vue and get the value, otherwise it doesn't

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('input[name="title"]').on('click keypress', function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();

        if(event.type === "keypress" &&( event.keyCode=='32' || event.charCode=='32') ){...}//space
        if(event.type === "keypress" &&( event.keyCode=='8' || event.charCode=='8') ){...}//backspace
        if(event.type === "click"{...}//click

        return true;
  });
```